# Why is my query returning an INT64 instead of a DATE?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I execute the following code:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE query STRING;
DECLARE CTY INT64;
DECLARE input_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris");

SET CTY = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM input_date);
SET query =
    """
    SELECT """||input_date||""", DATE(CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris")), """||CTY||"""
    """;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(query);

END;
```

But I get this result:

```js
[{
  "f0_": "1994",
  "f1_": "2023-10-18",
  "f2_": "2023"
}]
```

When I do not use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, I get the expected result.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE query STRING;
DECLARE CTY INT64;
DECLARE input_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris");

SET input_date = CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris");
SET CTY = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM input_date);

SELECT input_date, DATE(CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris")), CTY;

END;
```

```
[{
  "input_date": "2023-10-19",
  "f0_": "2023-10-19",
  "CTY": "2023"
}]
```

Why is the return for `input_date` an INT and not a DATE? Am I doing something wrong with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?

I had the issue in a bigger query so I isolated the part that caused problem. But I do not understand where the issue comes from. From my understanding, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE should not change the type of parameters.

I tried changing project and variables names.

I am expecting the two queries to give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is super obvious... **2023 - 10 - 19 = 1994**!

The query you're generating produces something like:

```
SELECT 2023-10-19, DATE(CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris")), 2023
```

You need to single-quote the date string like so:

```
SET query =
    """
    SELECT '"""||input_date||"""', DATE(CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris")), """||CTY||"""
    """;
```

So that it generates:

```
SELECT '2023-10-19', DATE(CURRENT_DATE("Europe/Paris")), 2023
```